# Causative - Passive/Active voice

Tags: grammar, causative-verbs

Would you agree to the following guidelines:

**In the Passive voice**, the causatives "have" and "get" have the same meaning, but 'get' is less formal

**In the Active voice**, the causatives "have" and "get" have a different meaning: Have (ask for a service),  Get (persuade)

Thank you

Comment: *They had us build a prototype.*   How would you recast that in the passive?

Comment: There is no "have" version of "Cake gets eaten at birthday parties."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four possible patterns with causative "have" and "get" are the following (I will use TRomano's example in the comment above):

1. They **had us build** a prototype.
2. They **had a prototype built**.
3. They **got us to build** a prototype.
4. They **got a prototype built**.

They are all in the active form, but (2) and (4) do not mention the builder and can thus be deemed to include a passive structure.

In (1) and (3) "have" and "get" are synonyms, meaning "persuade" or "order". Besides, according to the Longman dictionary causative "have" in pattern (1) is mainly AmE:

b) to persuade or order someone to do something

**have somebody do something** especially American English

*I’ll have Hudson show you to your room.*

22. to persuade or force someone to do something

**get somebody to do something**

*I’ll get Terry to check the wiring for me.*

*We couldn’t get him to sign the agreement.*